# Azure Blob storage azCopy replace container contents

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

Lets say I have container one with 3 files and I have container two with those same 3 files + 1 extra for a total of 4.

Is it possible to do a copy/replace so that container 2 only contains 3 files when doing azcopy?

Comment: Do you mean you want AzCopy to delete the 4th file in the "target" container, because that file does not exist in the first ("source") container?

Comment: If that is what you want, I'm not aware of any command line option in AzCopy to achieve it, but you might like to double check by scanning all the parameters listed on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy

Comment: @JohnRusk-MSFT I want to do an entire clone of source to destination, even if destination has additional blobs

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy currently don't support to delete any blobs, it focus on transfer blobs from source to destination.
You might can write your own code the compare the 2 container and do clean up.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I would think that a clone feature would be available for just this case when you need to sync containers

Comment: Upvoting feature request [AzCopy should support /MIR option like robocopy](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6930594-azcopy-should-support-mir-option-like-robocopy) would help make this happen in AzCopy.
I believe the `/MIR` option would deliver what OP (and me today) wants.